# Check this regular expression please

Tags: regex

I'm new to writing Regex's. I did a little bit of research and came up with this regex for the string:

> 7.0 GB of High-Speed Data Plus Unlimited^ Talk & Text (69.00)

Am I anything close to getting it right?

```
^(\\d{1}\\.\\d{1} \\s [G.t] \\s (\\d{2}\\.\\d{2})$
```

Comment: Have you tested it? What results did you see? And what language are you using regexes in?

Comment: i did'nt test it, how do I test it? Java

Comment: This site is very useful for quick testing: https://www.regex101.com/ . As for your regex, its not even valid. You have more `(` than `)`.

Comment: Write a short Java program that uses it, create a string, and see if it matches. Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html

Comment: Used regex101.com and got suggestion to remove {1}

Answer (score 1):

To match the string literally you can use:

```
^7\.0 GB of High-Speed Data Plus Unlimited\^ Talk & Text \(69\.00\)$
```

Now you can replace every number with \d{x} where x is the number of digits to match.

```
^\d{1}\.\d{1} GB of High-Speed Data Plus Unlimited\^ Talk & Text \(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)$
```

Now you can replace \d{1} with \d

```
^\d\.\d GB of High-Speed Data Plus Unlimited\^ Talk & Text \(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)$
```

Now you could replace some text with .* to match the text between GB and (

```
^\d\.\d GB.*\(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)$
```

Now you can add \s after GB so that there must be at least one space character after the GB

```
^\d\.\d GB\s.*\(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)$
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer to a regex question I've seen. People rarely explain how a regex is constructed, they just provide it. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language (there are slight variations).
Regular Expressions (regex) are used to find the matches in the string.
The first section is close, but the {1} is necessary and there's no need to group (using parenthesis).
`"^(\d{1}\.\d{1}..." --> "^\d\.\d..."` (you can also use`[0-9]`instead of`\d`)
The middle section can be made fairly simple with just a `.+`
The last section is slightly off.  Parathesis are used for grouping, so to match them you have to use the escape char ()
`"...(\d{2}\.\d{2})" --> "...\(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)$"`
Regex can be confusing at first, but there a lot of fun when you get used it to.  For practice, I try think of several regex that would match them some random sentances in an email, or file names, or product names on a website.
Keep practicing.  He's a good reference (found from a little googling) http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

`^\d\.\d.+\(\d{2}\.\d{2}\)$`

Let me know if you have any questions - enjoy.

Comment: I used the \d instead of [0-9]. But thank you for the refernce, it's really good.